# Electrostatics/conservation of charge

Tags: physics

Conservation of Charge states that "Charge cannot be created neither be destroyed."

If something cannot be created, then how it is in existence?

Comment: It is converted from something like battery chemical energy  (chemical reaction), or Solar energy or Hydro generators and magnetic motion of charges in conductors.

Comment: Previous comment is nonsense. Electrical energy is converted from other kinds of energy. Charge can not be created from energy (outside of some crazy particle accelerator scenario).

Comment: Charge is an inherent property of subatomic particles. This is more of a physics or philosophy question (I can't tell which) than an EE question.

Comment: The answer to this question goes back to the origin of the universe. Theoretical physicists working on the big bang theory are working on it.

Comment: Sounds like a religious question. How is it that the universe exists, at all? Ultimate Truth (capital-T, as opposed to little-t science truths) about reality questions are religious.

Comment: If you throw an electron into a black hole...

Answer (score 0):

Charge can be created and destroyed, as energy and matter can be created and destroyed. An instance I can think about is a positron and electron can interact to form two gamma ray photons, which have no charge. This interaction can also happen in reverse. There are many other ways for charge to be destroyed or created. In the classical sense, charge is conserved. And if your dealing with circuits, it can be considered that no charge is created or destroyed. And in most cases and almost any circuit analysis or EM theory it can be considered that charge is not created or destroyed.